# Python - Dictionary, Pickle

Tags: python

I'm taking an intro to Python class and I can't get my program to work. Here is the project explanation:

- Create a class named "Nation" with four instance variables to hold the data for a country and a method named popDensity that calculates the population density of the country. Write a program that uses the class to create a dictionary of 193 items, where each item of the dictionary has the form:
  name of a country: Nation object for that country
  Use the file "UN.txt" to create the dictionary, and save the dictionary in a pickled binary file named nationsDict.dat.

The "UN.txt" file basically contains a listing of country, continent, population, area (Example: Albania,Europe,3.0,11100)

Here is the program I created (using pythonanywhere.com):

```
import pickle

def main():
    createDictionaryofNations()

def createDictionaryofNations():
    nationdict = {}
    for line in open("UN.txt", 'r'):
        data = line.split(',')
        country = Nation()
        country.setName(data[0])
        country.setContinent(data[1])
        country.setPopulation (float(data[2]))
        country.setArea (float(data[3].rstrip()))
        nationdict[country.getName()] = country

    pickle.dump(nationdict, open("nationdict.dat", 'wb'))
    return nationdict

class Nation:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ""
        self._continent = ""
        self._population = 0.0
        self._area = 0

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self._name

    def setContinent(self, continent):
        self._continent = continent

    def getContinent(self):
        return self._continent

    def setPopulation(self, population):
        self._population = population

    def getPopulation(self):
        return self._population

    def setArea(self,area):
        self._area = area

    def getArea(self):
        return self._area

    def popDensity(self):
        return self._population / self._area

main()
```

It creates the `Nationdict.dat` file but it just contains these 5 characters `€}”.`

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I've been over this so many times and looked through tons of articles, help sites, etc, and can't figure out what I'm missing.

Appreciate it!

Jes

Comment: You can't properly look at a binary file in a text editor. Check the actual size of the file on disk.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing anything wrong, pickle generates a file that is not human readable. To check if it works run another program

```
import pickle
import so # so.py is my name of the file with your code from the question
print(pickle.load(open( "nationdict.dat", "rb")))
```

Comment: I ran the program and it came back as  {}  . Which I assumed was that it was coming back with nothing. I looked back at my UN.txt file and it was empty. I re-loaded that file ran the original program and am now getting this error - _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.Nation'>: it's not the same object as __main__.Nation    Maybe I'm just doomed to fail this class!

Comment: Have you considered pickling nations as arrays?

Comment: I have not because I haven't learned that yet. :) Can you give me a further explanation? I tried searching and I'm getting things that look way over my head.

Comment: You must have learned that. I meant pickling `[data[0], data[1], float(data[2]), float(data[3].rstrip())]` as custom classes as not picklable.

Comment: I have not or perhaps have not learned well enough about it to understand. Like I said, this is literally my first class and it's an online/text book class. I've been supplementing my class materials with anything online that I can find but still struggling.

Comment: I will edit my answer so as to it includes runnable code